# Connecting to Ubuntu web server running in a VM created with Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server, osx-mavericks

I am attempting to setup a local development environment so that I can keep my development work from bogging down my VPS; leaving it for production code only. I am having trouble connecting to the server through a web browser, I continually get a "Safari cannot connect to the server" error. I have tried/established:

- Adding ServerName to the httpd.conf file, setting it to localhost
- In the ports.conf file, Listen is set to 80. I tried changing it to *:80

Here are the "conditions" of my situation:

- Host OS: OSX 10.9 Mavericks
- Guest OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04.3
- Using Virtual Box to create the VM

I can SSH to the server just fine, but again, I cannot access the server via http in a browser.

Comment: Just a few checks: Did your restart apache after modifying the configuration? Is Apache actually listening on port 80 of the server's IP address? Did you check if there's a firewall blocking port 80 to the server?

Comment: Yes, I did restart apache. As for your second question, like I said the config file reads: "Listen 80", as far as I know, that means it is. Lastly, the firewall on my computer is not active, and I don't believe there is one on the server either considering "ufw" is not installed.

Comment: Regarding 2: there can be a difference between configuration and what's actually happening. So check using `lsof -i`. Regarding the firewall: check with `iptables -xnvL`, ufw is just a wrapper.

Comment: Executing the first command prints 8 lines, three of those lines include "*:http (LISTEN)", nothing says "*:80". As for the second command, chain INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT all say ACCEPT.

Comment: ok, so apache is listening and there's no firewall. What happens when you telnet to port 80 of the server?

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution, but because of my low reputation, I cannot post it. I just added a port forwarding rule to forward: 127.0.0.1:8080 to 10.0.2.15:80. It looks like something may be blocking port 80, although I am not sure what.

Comment: @AlecCarpenter, you could also change the networking mode to "bridged" rather than NAT.  The reason you have to forward a port is that the VM is sitting behind NAT and on a different network than your host machine.  Bridging will put your VM on the same network as your host.

Comment: Sounds like another process is listening on port 80. The `lsof -i` output should tell you which.

Comment: I just remembered I have MAMP Pro installed, so that may be it, although it isn't currently running. But I don't see anything in the output of `lsof -i` that says any process is listening on port 80.

Comment: @heavyd I have tried that too, although I was never successful, I still get "unable to connect" or "connection refused" errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out, thanks to those who helped!

My solution was to add a port forwarding rule to the network settings of the virtual machine in VirtualBox. (Choose an existing virtual machine -> Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding) Inside of port forwarding, I added a rule like:

127.0.0.1:8080 (forward to) 10.0.2.15:80

Now when I type `http://127.0.0.1:8080` into the browser, I am served the default "It Works" page. This leads me to believe that there is something blocking port 80, but if this works, I don't see a need to try and fix that.

Comment: Based on what you're now telling you were just testing it wrong. Localhost on your machine without the portforward is something different than 10.0.2.15, so of course that would not work. I assumed you tried to open 10.0.2.15 in your browser (which will most likely just work) since that's the IP your server is using.

Comment: @TeunVink I have tried that also, but I still get an "unable to connect" error.